# get url id in php and display result in html

Tags: php, html, mysql, url

Hi i have written this code in order to get the news id from url and display the news result from this id which is stored in mysql. I dont know what i am doing wrong. But i am getting any output. I have also test my query which is running fine in mysql.I am doing small misatke which is not able to identif may be syntax or quotation somewhere. Thanks.
Here is my Url:

```
http://autodo/admin/news.php?id=2043
```

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
   $ID=$_GET['id']; 
   $sql="   SELECT DISTINCT ad_news.datum, ad_news_texte.text, ad_news_texte.headline, ad_news_texte.id
                    FROM autodo.ad_news_texte, autodo.ad_news
                    WHERE ad_news_texte.id =".$ID."
                    GROUP BY ad_news_texte.text, ad_news_texte.headline, ad_news_texte.id";
  echo $sql_select=mysql_query($sql);
   if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_select)){       
            $news_id= $row['id'];   
            $news_datum= $row['datum']; 
          $news_text= $row['text']; 
            $news_headline= $row['headline']; 
?>
<div class="welcome-rahmen lng toggleNews" id="<?= $news_id ?> ">
<p class="welcome-breadcrump"><?= $news_datum ?></p>
<p class="welcome-subheadline"><?= $news_headline ?></p>
<div class="newsText">
<?= $news_text ?>
</div>
</div>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: use single quotes for id '$id'

Comment: no its not the correct way ...

Comment: When you are adding variables to an sql query you need to wrap them in quotes, I.E. SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myVal='value', so in your code where you have this =>( WHERE ad_news_texte.id =".$ID." ) you should replace it with this =>     ( WHERE ad_news_texte.id ='".$ID." ') by putting the single quotes on the inside of your query on either side of your variable input you are telling the php to give sql a statement like this => ( WHERE ad_news_texte.id='theValueFromID' ) instead of ( WHERE ad_news_texte.id=theValueFromID )

Comment: i have written '".$ID."' like you said but still its not working :(. I am returning single row every time so do i need to if or while lopp i m confused in that. May be because of looping error or condition i m not getting output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should concatenate $ID and sql string by `.`

For example:

```
 $sql="   SELECT DISTINCT ad_news.datum, ad_news_texte.text, ad_news_texte.headline, ad_news_texte.id
                    FROM autodo.ad_news_texte, autodo.ad_news
                    WHERE ad_news_texte.id =".$ID."
                    GROUP BY ad_news_texte.text, ad_news_texte.headline, ad_news_texte.id";
```

Comment: Please check my updated question according to your answers but still its not working :(

Comment: can you check your query executed successfully by if (!$sql_select) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

Answer (score 1):

Some mistakes,

1. You mixing [shorthand](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) and echo for printing output.
2. Missing `;` semi-colon at end of echo statment.
3. Syntax error in query

Firstly turn on your errors adding `ini_set("display_errors",1);` on top of your file.
Use below statemnt for everywhere you output the variable,

```
<?php echo $news_id; ?>
```

Or,

```
<?= $news_id ?>
```

Query should be,

```
$sql=" SELECT DISTINCT ad_news.datum, ad_news_texte.text, ad_news_texte.headline, ad_news_texte.id
                    FROM autodo.ad_news_texte, autodo.ad_news
                    WHERE ad_news_texte.id = '$ID'
                    GROUP BY ad_news_texte.text, ad_news_texte.headline, ad_news_texte.id";
```

**Waring:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: no i tried semicolon but nothing is getting. Can you please check my query in that i am writing id as "$ID" in where clause ... is it right way ? because if my query is not correct then also it qill not return anything...

Comment: Updated my answer. Kindly check.

Comment: Where you are calling id as "$ID", since you are trying to add the string value of that variable to the query, you need to concatenate it as such, 'Your query here"' . $ID .  '" The rest of your query here.'  a period is PHP's concatenation symbol, and will combine the 3 string segments you have currently

Comment: please check the updated question where i have made changes according to your answers

Comment: Comapre my query and yours it's not same.

Answer (score 1):

first change quote to variable in where of query like

```
WHERE ad_news_texte.id ='$ID'
```

then no use of echo in

`<?= echo $news_datum ?>` try in all of your code `<?= $news_datum ?>`

so your whole code will be

```
<?php
   $ID=$_GET['id']; 
   $sql="SELECT DISTINCT ad_news.datum, ad_news_texte.text, ad_news_texte.headline, ad_news_texte.id FROM autodo.ad_news_texte, autodo.ad_news WHERE ad_news_texte.id ='$ID' GROUP BY ad_news_texte.text, ad_news_texte.headline, ad_news_texte.id";
  $sql_select=mysql_query($sql);
  $checkrow = mysql_num_rows($sql_select);
  if($checkrow > 0) {
     if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_select)){       
            $news_id= $row['id'];   
            $news_datum= $row['datum']; 
          $news_text= $row['text']; 
            $news_headline= $row['headline']; 
    ?>
     <div class="welcome-rahmen lng toggleNews" id="<?= $news_id ?> ">
    <p class="welcome-breadcrump"><?= $news_datum ?></p>
    <p class="welcome-subheadline"><?= $news_headline ?></p>
   <div class="newsText">
   <?= $news_text ?><?php } 
 }
 else {
   echo 'query does not return any rows';
 }?>
```

Comment: '$ID' its not correct man its taking it as a string and my id is not a string ...can you please check my updated question ...

Comment: @user3702602 query var need to be quoted if this is string or both will be get in query please give a try this and let me know

Comment: then need to run your query in phpmyadmin or check it returning any rows check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You have used `<?= echo` - `<?=` alone is the same as `<?php echo` Additionally, as another pointed out you are missing several `;` at the end of lines.

Regardless, I would encourage you to use prepared statements or otherwise sanitize the data you are pulling from the query string as your query as written is vulnerable to SQL injection.